# create dialog that doesn't block the main app mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using mfc, is there any way to create a dialog that doesn't block the main app without using threads?
if yes, how can i do it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Call the `Create` function instead of `DoModal`.

Comment: then how can i know the dialog result `int iReturn = m_RedesignSheet.DoModal()` ? @CodyGray

Comment: @AmirYouhana google "mfc modeless dialog"

Comment: Non-modal dialogs don't return a result. They don't return at all. Just like regular windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [modeless dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w2h2y4y.aspx). Click the link for more details.

There is a good tutorial about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC).

Example to display:

```
CModeLess *m_pmodeless = new CModeLess(this);
m_pmodeless->Create(CModeLess::IDD);
m_pmodeless->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

I won't repeat the tutorial but it explains how you using **messages** to relay to the parent what the dialog result is.